# Conditional debugging in VS Community and C#

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2013

Imagine you had a function that run for every item in a list, but you only care about the item with id 5. Is there a way to not touch the code and have to re-compile just to debug on the inside of an if statement... or is there a more debuggy immediate way.

I could do this:

```
if( id == 5 )
{
    int a = -1; // Place breakpoint here
}
```

But it's annoying to re-compile just so I can sling a breakpoint on that line.

I really look forward to the answer on this!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why you just cannot set condition break point using visual studio

check this link of my blog for the same : [Help Yourself in Debugging (Part-2) using Breakpoint/Tracepoint](http://pranayamr.blogspot.no/2013/11/help-yourself-in-debugging-part-2-using.html)

Comment: This has already been answered in the duplicate, no need to promote your blog for that in my opinion. :)

Comment: @CodeCaster - ok i will take care of it ..i provided blog link because its having screen shot of how to set it also infomation about tracepoint which is also help full